# call a function inside a function from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and in my app.js file I have tow main functions:

1. $(document).ready(function (){});
2. $(window).on("load", function (){});

my code looks like this:

```js
$(function () {
  
  // code
  // code
  
  function myFunction(){
    // code
  }

});

$(window).on("load", function () {
  // I want to use myFunction() here but I cant because it's not accessible from here
  myFunction();
});
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes: Don't make functions inside of other functions. There is literally no reason to, and you're just setting up scope problems for yourself

Comment: Why would you declare your function within your $(document).ready()? Just declare your function outside of it.

Comment: Why don't you declare the `myFunction()` outside (as in) globally?

Comment: I read somewhere that you shouldn't declare more than 4 - 8 global functions. slows down the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.lib = {
  onWindowLoad: function () {
    ...
  },

 onDocReady: function() {
   ...
  },

  evenmore: {
    nested: function(){
     ...
    }
  }
}

$(window).on("load", function () {
  lib.onWindowLoad();
});
```

There would be many other ways to do so.

<sub><sup>In case, if you need to read something somewhere, [that's here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)</sup></sub>